# universal reference c++11 code duplication

Tags: c++, c++11, dry, universal-reference

In my project I have function like this:

```
bool VectorList::put(const Pair &p);
```

This adds the `Pair` into the `VectorList` by copying the `Pair`.

I can use it like this:

```
Pair p { "key", "value" };

VectorList v;
v.put(p);

// or
v.put(Pair{ "anotherkey", "anothervalue" });
```

However in second case an unnecessary object is created, so I want to do

```
bool VectorList::put(Pair &&p);
```

I checked how this is done in vector (gcc, llvm) and there is 100% same code in both methods, except equal / std::move() line.

Is there some way I could do it without code duplication?

---

`put()` looks similar to this:

```
struct Node{
    Pair pair;
    AdditionalThings at;
};

bool VectorList::put(const Pair &p){
    if (not_good_for_insert(p))
         return false;
    // ...
    Node node = create_node();
    node.pair = p;
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use [perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward):

```
template <typename P>
bool VectorList::put (P &&p) {
    //can't forward p here as it could move p and we need it later
    if (not_good_for_insert(p)) 
     return false;
    // ...
    Node node = create_node();
    node.pair = std::forward<P>(p);
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

Another possibility is to just pass by value like in [Maxim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32778410/496161). The advantage of the perfect-forwarding version is that it requires no intermediate conversions if you pass in compatible arguments and performs better if moves are expensive. The disadvantage is that forwarding reference functions are very greedy, so other overloads might not act how you want.

Note that `Pair &&p` is not a universal reference, it's just an rvalue reference. Universal (or forwarding) references require an rvalue in a deduced context, like template arguments.

Comment: can you pls elaborate how code will look like if I have something like this -    struct Node{ Pair pair, SomethingElse se } xx;  xx.pair = p;  I will edit the question as well.

Comment: do i need template if I know my type will always be Pair?

Comment: can't I do just: node.pair = std::forward<Pair>(p); I mean, it is a typename after all?

Comment: @Nick no, that's not how forwarding references work. Please read [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c/).

Answer (score 2):

The ideal solution is to accept a universal reference, as [TartanLlama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32778379/412080) advises.

The ideal solution works if you can afford having the function definition in the header file. If your function definition cannot be exposed in the header (e.g. you employ Pimpl idiom or interface-based design, or the function resides in a shared library), the second best option is to accept by value. This way the caller can choose how to construct the argument (copy, move, uniform initialization). The callee will have to pay the price of one move though. E.g. `bool VectorList::put(Pair p);`:

```
VectorList v;
Pair p { "key", "value" };
v.put(p); 
v.put(std::move(p));
v.put(Pair{ "anotherkey", "anothervalue" });
v.put({ "anotherkey", "anothervalue" });
```

And in the implementation you move from the argument:

```
bool VectorList::put(Pair p) { container_.push_back(std::move(p)); }
```

---

Another comment is that you may like to stick with standard C++ names for container operations, like `push_back/push_front`, so that it is clear what it does. `put` is obscure and requires readers of your code to look into the source code or documentation to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

With help of TartanLlama, I made following test code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(int s2) : s(s2){
        std::cout << "c-tor " << s << std::endl;
    }

    MyClass(MyClass &&other) : s(other.s){
        other.s = -1;

        std::cout << "move c-tor " << s << std::endl;
    }

    MyClass(const MyClass &other) : s(other.s){
        std::cout << "copy c-tor " << s << std::endl;
    }

    ~MyClass(){
        std::cout << "d-tor " << s << std::endl;
    }

public:
    int s;
};

// ==============================

template <typename T>
MyClass process(T &&p){
    MyClass out = std::forward<T>(p);

    return out;
}

// ==============================

void t1(){
    MyClass out = process( 100 );
}

void t2(){
    MyClass out = process( MyClass(100) );
}

void t3(){
    MyClass in  = 100;
    MyClass out = process(std::move(in));

    std::cout <<  in.s << std::endl;
    std::cout << out.s << std::endl;
}

void t4(){
    MyClass in  = 100;
    MyClass out = process(in);

    std::cout <<  in.s << std::endl;
    std::cout << out.s << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::cout << "testing fast c-tor"   << std::endl;   t1();   std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "testing c-tor"        << std::endl;   t2();   std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "testing move object"  << std::endl;   t3();   std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "testing normal object"    << std::endl;   t4();   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output on gcc is following:

```
testing fast c-tor
c-tor 100
d-tor 100

testing c-tor
c-tor 100
move c-tor 100
d-tor -1
d-tor 100

testing move object
c-tor 100
move c-tor 100
-1
100
d-tor 100
d-tor -1

testing normal object
c-tor 100
copy c-tor 100
100
100
d-tor 100
d-tor 100
```